# Is it possible to add HTML elements in which store some data in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For example i need to show array elements in an `<ul>` and each elements should begin with `<li>` and end with `</li>`.
Thats the code i wrote but it doesn't work at all:

```
clearedtaskslist: function(){
this.template='<ul>'      
for(let i=0;i<this.archive.length;i++)
{
  this.template+= '<li>' + this.archive[i].task '</li>'
}
this.template+='</ul>'
}
```

is it possible to do something like that in vue?

edit

i need to show data throught various events , i tried with v-for but only the last events will print data.
for example in my app i have to show on a below section the completed task and the user who completed them so i need to show this 2 data each time someone trigger the relative event

```
clearedtaskslist: function(){
      
for(let i=0;i<this.archive.length;i++)
{
  this.template += 'Task:  ' + this.archive[i].task 
  this.template +=  ' user: ' + this.archive[i].taskuserID + '----||----'
}

}
```

thats how i take the data(that string concatenation its horrible i know) and then i should break the line on eache for cycle (and i don't know how to do it)

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 25px;" class="w-50">
   <h5 v-if="archive.length>0"><i>Completed tasks</i></h5>
  <div style="margin:0 auto;"> <p>{{template}}</p> </div>
</div>
```

and that is where the data are shown

so the point is to make possible to style this data properly with no horrible string concat, is there some way to do that with vue?

Comment: Hi did you check official Vue docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: This is in direct conflict with how VueJS should be used: you shouldn't be storing data per se in markup. The data should come from a single source of truth (e.g. your component data), and then you use the template to visualize/render them, since the template is reactive and will re-render based on changes in your data. In your case, you will want to look at using `v-for` to loop through `this.archive`.

Comment: Try to create a basic `to-do CRUD app` (You find a lot of examples/tutorials). After one of these tutorials, You will get a lot of ideas for working correctly with lists/props/data (As Terry said - your example "not reactive" + Not clean). Example: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-to-do-app-with-vue-js-2. More about vue Reactivity : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Answer (score 0):

With a few assumptions, I wrote an example of a similar scenario to yours. Of course, you would need to adjust it to your needs as I am not fully aware of the scope of your application.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button
        v-for="(user, index) of getUniqueUsers"
        :key="user+index"
        @click="selectedUser=user"
      >User: {{user}}</button>
    </div>
    <ul v-if="selectedUser">
      <li
        v-for="(task, index) of archive.filter((user) => user.taskuserID==selectedUser)"
        :key="task+index"
      >
        <p>User: {{task.taskuserID}}</p>
        <p>Task: {{task.task}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      selectedUser: null,
      archive: [
        {
          taskuserID: "1",
          task: "task1"
        },
        {
          taskuserID: "2",
          task: "task3"
        },
        {
          taskuserID: "1",
          task: "task3"
        },
        {
          taskuserID: "4",
          task: "task4"
        },
        {
          taskuserID: "5",
          task: "task1"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    getUniqueUsers() {
      const uniqueUsers = [
        ...new Set(this.archive.map(user => user.taskuserID))
      ];
      return uniqueUsers;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
</style>
```

---

- In my example, I used a sample archive data property which is an `array of objects` where I store `taskuserID`
  and `task`.
- I used `computed` property to get a unique `taskuserID` from the archive
  `array`.
- Based on the `return` value from `computed` property (sorted `array`) I looped through unique users with `v-for` in order to create a button for each user.
- When you press on the button, in the loop below it will show all tasks completed by that specific `taskuserID` in a list. I used `v-for` for that with `selectedUser` data property that keeps track of the user who has been selected. Based on that value I filter the archive `array` in order to show all of the relevant tasks for the selected user.

**[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-river-lbbwj?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)**